# Angular flex layout: Parent element with fxLayout="column" affects height not width of child element

Tags: css, angular, flexbox

I have a parent element that applies `fxLayout="column"`.
Inside the parent element I have a child element that applies fxFlex="80".

In this case, `fxFlex="80"` affects the height of the child element not the width.
I get the expected result when changing the parent flex-layout to row.

How can I achieve the expected results with `fxLayout="column"` and still using this declarative style?

Comment: So you want width of 80%?

Comment: Yes but still using the flex layout directives

Comment: Not sure that's possible, flexbox "properties" only work in one dimension based on the flex-direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try something like this?

```html
<div fxLayout="row">
  <div fxLayout="column" fxFlex="80">
    <!-- place other elements here -->
  <div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The above answer worked for me, for my specific case I had to set the wrapping element's height and width to 100%

```
<div class="wrapper" fxLayout="row">
  <div fxLayout="column" fxFlex="80">
    <!-- place other elements here -->
  <div>
</div>
```

// CSS

```
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
 }
```